# Configuring the install location for eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to set where my app will be installed, so far I have tried to put the path into

```
android:installLocation="android/data/com/installedpath"
```

But the error said i wrote the wrong format, so do you guys know the correct format for the Install Location part?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According Android Development Guide (http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/data/install-location.html), this attribute could contain two values: "preferExternal" or "auto".
And its use is to allow to install the application on external storage.